# How to process 'stock.immediate.transfer' records on Odoo 15?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I recently switched from Odoo 13 to Odoo 15. With Odoo 13, I could process 'stock.picking' with

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'stock.immediate.transfer',
                                            'create',
                                            ({'pick_ids': [pickid]})
    )
   
   models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'stock.immediate.transfer', 'process',
                                [createdid], {})
```

However now with Odoo 15, running the same process processes and returns True but the stock picking record does not close. I looked at the documentation but did not see anything regarding how to process immediate transfers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [process](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/stock/wizard/stock_immediate_transfer.py#L63) function has changed, now it prepares the stock pickings then call again the `button_validate` function to process transfers, and to do so, it will first check if [button_validate_picking_ids](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/stock/wizard/stock_immediate_transfer.py#L59) are passed through the context.

Note that even if the function did call the `button_validate` function again it will return `True` and if you call `button_validate` manually after you call the `process` function, the transfer will be processed and passed to the `done` state.

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'stock.picking', 'button_validate', [picking_ids])
```

You can reproduce the same logic to process a transfer (pass the context to the wizard `process` function):

```py
action = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'stock.picking', 'button_validate', [picking_ids])

values = {'pick_ids': [(6, 0, picking_ids)], 
          'immediate_transfer_line_ids': [(0, 0, {'to_immediate': True, 'picking_id': pick_id}) for pick_id in picking_ids]}

transfer_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'stock.immediate.transfer', 'create', [values])
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'stock.immediate.transfer', 'process', [transfer_id], {'context': action['context']})
```